# apt-get update Failing

Tags: apt, kali-linux, software-updates

I am getting the following message when trying to run `sudo apt-get update` on my Kali virtual machine. What could be the cause?

```
root@kali:~# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease [3,415 B]
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done       
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@kali:~#
```

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search *omitted*.com
nameserver 192.168.10.240
nameserver 192.168.32.215
```

Comment: Type us the output of `# cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Added in resolv.conf

Comment: Does `sudo apt clean` an the `sudo apt update` change the situation?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add an `s` in the first `http`:

```
deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe You are right... I don't have a source of kali repositories so didn't want to post the wrong line. I edit the answer with the official repo from kali.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing from http to https by using nano
type :
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
then :
change url fro http :// to https://

Comment: This duplicates an old answer.

Answer (score 0):

for me It didn't worked by adding just 's' in http, in fact, Kali doesn't use the https.
However, I found out my internet provider was blocking this website 'kali.org' because I have opted the child safety 'on'. as soon as I whitelist the 'kali.org' on their website by login to my internet provided account. all went through without any error.